# iptables -L is slow even with just 2 ip's blocked

Tags: iptables

Does somebody know why iptables -L is slow  even with just 2 ip's blocked ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
iptables -n -L
```

to avoid reverse DNS lookups

Comment: excelent. this is the solution.